# Why not cease מוריד הגשם at שחרית according to רמ״א?

Tags: passover, shacharis-morning-prayer, chutz-laaretz, nusach-ashkenaz, geshem-tal-ruach

The rabbi spoke today during prayer services and made the following points (inter alia; and I've no citations for most of them):

- The time to cease saying "מוריד הגשם" and start saying "מוריד הטל" is the first day of פסח.

  - We'd switch as soon as that time arrived, namely at מעריב; the reason given for not doing so is that many people are not in the synagogue for מעריב and won't know to switch.
  - We'd switch at the next opportunity, at שחרית; the reason given for not doing so is that we want to announce, before the עמידה, that people should say "מוריד הטל", and can't do so during שחרית as it would constitute an interruption between גאולה and תפלה.
  - So we switch at מוסף.
- רמ״א says not to say "מוריד הטל" at all. He also says not to announce "we stop saying 'מוריד הגשם'", as it is like praying for no rain. Thus, the community switches only after the שליח צבור does so in his repetition of the עמידה of מוסף, and there's never a pre-עמידה announcement. (This is מנהג נוסח אשכנז outside of Israel.)

It seems then that according to רמ״א the reason to switch at מוסף and not שחרית is nonexistent. So why not switch at שחרית?

Comment: Perhaps the switch was already instituted at musaf according to those who say morid hatal?

Comment: There is the since they might think they started at maariv answer, as mentioned by kouty, but does that really answer your question? Isn't your question asking according to the geulah-tefila reason? These are two different ways of approaching the musaf issue

Comment: @Double AA the geula tefila reason seems to be relevant for shita that disagree with few people in shmini a. But for arvit of pesach there is no machloket and this taam is not needed. geula litfila is pb for shacharit and arvit. So if everybody is at shul in arvit, this helps not. This last shita thinks that the begining is afier announciation, the first shita did not tell about announciation

Answer (score 1):

Both explanations comes from the Rosh in the first chapter of Taanit and the source is the Yerushalmi, we see that they are two contradictory pshatim in Yerushalmi. This Yerushalmi needs a serious reflection and is commented by acharonim and rishonim.

Anyway, I found somewhat which answer quickly your question.

First, here is [the page](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?pgnum=395&req=40739&st=) with the comment I used.

You ask:

> `We'd switch at the next opportunity, at שחרית; the reason given for not doing so is that we want to announce, before the עמידה, that people should say "מוריד הטל", and can't do so during שחרית as it would constitute an interruption between גאולה and תפלה.`

This is a mixture of two meimrot in Yerushalmi. The Rosh himself reports the Yerushalmi with all details.

The Yerushalmi  (paraphrased following the conclusion) says that if he bring to his attention that the members of congregation says morid hatal in shacharit. He discovers this listening the chazarat hashats or before thanks to his neighbor. At this step at least (see later), the gemara rules that members of the congregation and the officiant switch simultaneously. So he would think that yesterday in Arvit he did erroneously say morid hageshem. He believe that he should pray immediately tashlumim for the arvit prayer. Or two prayers, shacharit and arvit if he did discover the switch by the shaliach tsibur.

Thus, for the minhag not to mention Tal, there is also a problem if they switch in shacharit.

I though twice this teruts. You can find somewhat similar in the perush שירי קרבן in the PDF linked above.

This is not the single answer to the OP but is perhaps enough.

Comment: @msh210 I hope that this answer is decipherable. I advise you to read carefully the Yerushalmy anyway.